# Can't get acces to hMailServer

Tags: routing, email-server, configuration

I'm trying to put in place a mail server with hmail server.

My company has the "mycompany.com" domain name (at http://en.gandi.net/).

On my web domain provider interface, I add manually an email account for each user (user@mycompany.com) in my company with their private correspending email (user@yahoo.com for example) so that the user can receive the "user@mycompany.com" in its private mail box.

With the mail server (companymail), I can get the mails destinated for "user@yahoo.com" LOCALLY (when I work on the server).

But, the problem is that when I put hmail on a distant server, I can't get access to it. When a user, for example, wants to get access to the "user@companymail" with a mail client, he  gets a message telling him that the server couldn't be found.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely issues:

**Something between you and the remote server is preventing the connection**

For instance, many ISPs block outbound tcp/25 to servers other than their own.  This should be fairly easy to check for since the don't usually block POP or IMAP.  It could be something else though too.

**Something other than hMail on the remote server is blocking the connection**

In other words, the software firewall running on the Windows machine.  The method to address this varies based on what version of Windows you're running, but in Windows 7 you could add rules in Control Panels -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules.

**hMail is not allowing remote connections**

My hMail install was put in place a while ago so I can't remember what the defaults are, but it's possible that, for security reasons, it only listens to 127.0.0.1 by default.  Check Settings -> Advanced -> TCP/IP Ports in the hMailAdministrator tool to see what IPs and ports the protocols are binding to.  On my server they are bound to 0.0.0.0 meaning they are listening on every available IP, you might have it set to 127.0.01, meaning you wouldn't be able to connect from a remote client.

The other place to check in the admin tool is Advanced -> IP Ranges.  In my server I have two - "My Computer", which allows access to everything from 127.0.0.1, and "Internet", which is any IP.  In the "Internet" range, I have the "Allow connections" boxes for SMTP, POP3, and IMAP unchecked, that seems like another likely source of your problem.